# How to run for loop that is inside shell script file from PHP file?

Tags: php, shell

I have a a shell script (`myscript.sh`), which contains many bash commands. I want to run these command from a php file (`index.php`).

I used `exec` to execute the commands as following:

```
$contents = file_get_contents('../folder/myscript.sh');
$output = null;
$return_var = null;
exec($contents, $output, $return_var);
print_r($contents);
print_r($return_var);
print_r($output);
```

Here is the content of `myscript.sh`

```
VAR1=("somePath/allDirs")
ls
cd ..
ls
for DIR in "${VAR1[@]}"; do
  echo "Name is $DIR"
done
pwd
....... other 5 lines of commands
```

All commands before the loop is working i.e: `ls` and `cd ..` and I got the output. However, the for loop is not working and it stop executing the rest of the commands after it.

My question is: how to execute this for loop that is inside shell script file from php file?

note: the for loop contains more command here I just put the echo to make the code easy to read and clear.

Comment: Are you saying that echo "Name is $DIR" is not executed? Never?

Comment: yes, it never even start the for loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you mutating the contents of the script at all? Why not just execute the script file rather than passing in the contents of the script? Regardless, if you must pass the contents directly to exec, pass it to `bash -c` and escape the command contents:

```php
$contents = file_get_contents('../folder/myscript.sh');
$output = null;
$return_var = null;
$contents = escapeshellarg($contents);
exec("bash -c $contents", $output, $return_var);
```

Comment: That's works. Now it goes through all commands, but I have inside the loop a mkdir command and I see in my folders structure no new directories are created on the localhost. Here is the command: `mkdir -p ../testDir/$DIR` . I can't see the test or the new DIR.

Comment: Does that command work in the shell when you execute it directly (subbing $DIR with whatever)?

Comment: Yes, when I run the myscript.sh through the terminal everything is perfect.

Comment: Does the 'echo "Name is $DIR"' output correctly from within the exec inside PHP?

Comment: yes, it shows the output correctly for everything. But it does not generate or create folders on the sever

Comment: My only thought is that the script for some reason doesn't contain the mkdir or something. I'd add some debugging echo statements to your script to figure out what's going on.

Comment: It contains some mkdir and creates some excel files also, but nothing of them is created when I run it through php

Comment: Might be a permissions issue. If you're running the php script under another user, that could prevent files and folders from being modified.

Comment: Yes, it was a permission issue. Thank you for your help